# Area of Domain as.Sum of Power Series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, conformal-geometry

> Suppose that f is a one-to-one analytic function mapping the disc $|z|<1$ onto a bounded domain D. Show that the area of D is given by $$A(D)=\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n|a_n|^2$$, where $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n$ is the power series for f in $|z|<1$.

This is a practice problem from Fisher's complex variables chapter 3.5 and I can use the fact that $$A(D)=\int \int_{|z|<1} {|f'(z)|}^2 dxdy$$ for the above problem. I am not sure where to start but I am considering using the summation of singularities and cauchy integral to get the result (although I am not sure how to apply them.)

Comment: Differentiate term by term and use polar coordinates to evaluate the double integral..

Comment: and then it would equal to the double integral of |f'(z)|^2? if so, i am not sure how to convert it to polar coordinates, can you show it for just one term thanks

Comment: Use $dxdy=rd\theta dr$ and $|f'(z)|^2=f'(z)\bar f'(z)$ multiply  term by term and use orthogonality to get rid of the cross terms when you integrate $d\theta$ so remain with only diagonal terms that are functions of $r$ only; technically to switch series and integrals you need uniform convergence so one does it first on the disc of radius $\rho$ and then let $\rho \to 1$